Stotras and mantras of lord Hayagriva
What are some mantras and stotras related to Hayagriva . How can we worship him to get his blessings . Which texts mention his emergence ,qualities and mantras?

Hayagriva Stotram by Vedanta Desika is considered very effective for education.
https://stotranidhi.com/hi/sri-hayagriva-stotram-in-sanskrit/
It takes about 5 minutes to recite.

Which texts mention the stotra?

https://ramanuja.org/desika.html lists all the works of Vedanta Desika,  Since Hayagriva Stotram is only a prayer - it is probably not referred to much by other works. @Sillyasker
